# Visual Basic 2010 - Referencing objects in different user controls

Tags: vb.net, object, reference, user-controls

For an app that uses user controls instead of forms and the first user control has a listview, where the user clicks or selects "Create New" Or Delete, what is the best way to transfer the data selected in the listview to the detail screen (separate User Control) where the data can be edited?

Can I just reference the list view in the first UC in the Details UC? something like:

```
ucHeader.lvSetups.FocusedItem.SubItems.Count = 0
```

from the ucDetail user control?

Answer (score 0):

Saying which way is the best would produce a heated discussion with every ones opinion.  However, here are a few ways I would tackle this. While there are more options, these are what I would do:

1. You should expose any information you want to read from a user control in the form of a property, readonly if you must. Just an example because I don't know what your object types are:

   Public ReadOnly Property SelectedItem as object
       get
           Return Listview1.SelectedValue
       end get
   End Property
2. You can also use events to tell the parent of your user control that a selection was made. You can pass whatever you want in this event, even the selected object. If you don't want to pass the selected object, grab it from the property you created (like #1) in the event handler.

Comment: Not sure why the code looks strange, I even used a language tag.